# Warning printed after migrating to Spring Boot 3.0 & Spring Integration 6.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

After migrating a project from Spring Boot v2.7 to v3.0 (and thus from Spring Integration v5.5 to v6.0), the following warnings are printed out:

```
WARN 22084 --- [  restartedMain] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.foobar.MyClassA
WARN 22084 --- [  restartedMain] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.foobar.MyClassB
WARN 22084 --- [  restartedMain] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.foobar.MyClassC
WARN 22084 --- [  restartedMain] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.foobar.MyClassD
```

`MyClassA` extends `IntegrationFlowAdapter`, and is annotated with `@Component`:

```java
package com.foobar;

@Component
class MyClassA extends IntegrationFlowAdapter {
  // …
}
```

`MyClassB` is annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```java
package com.foobar;

@ConfigurationProperties("my-config")
class MyClassB {
  // …
}
```

`MyClassC` is annotated with `@Configuration`:

```java
package com.foobar;

@Configuration
class MyClassC {
  // …
}
```

And this particular one not even extending anything, nor annotated:

```java
package com.foobar;

class MyClassD {
  // …
}
```

I didn’t see any relevant information in the [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide) and [Spring Integration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-5.x-to-6.0-Migration-Guide) migration guides. There is a [section](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#simplified-main-class-name-resolution-with-gradle) about *name resolution* in the Spring Boot migration guide, but it is related to Gradle, and I’m using Maven. I’m not even sure what this name resolution is all about.

I’m puzzled with the class `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer`, and I’m not sure what migration task I’m supposed to do.

Comment: What you need to do is in the message. There is more documentation then just Spring Boot and Spring Integration. Spring Boot is build on top of Spring Framework, which has this change (and also the documentation for it). https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x (Core Container).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Morgan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74601911) provides the correct fix, but I want to show some code to explain why this happens.

Given the following @Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean(FooBar foo, FooBar bar) {
        return new SomeBean(foo, bar);
    }

    @Bean
    public FooBar foo() {
        return new FooBar();
    }

    @Bean
    public FooBar bar() {
        return new FooBar();
    }
}
```

When creating the bean `someBean`, Spring must know which beans to use for each of the two parameters of the `someBean()` method. It does this by looking at the parameter names of the method (i.e. `foo` and `bar`) and compares it with the name of existing beans. The deprecated [LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.html) is used to resolve the parameter names of the method.

However, the parameter names are only kept after the compilation of the Java classes if the `-debug` flag is passed to the `javac` compiler. By default, the Maven compiler plugin does pass this flag to javac. That's why `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer` can do its job and why the warning is emitted.

With the code above, one can try to change the configuration of the Maven compiler plugin not to pass the debug flag to javac:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <debug>false</debug>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After compiling and executing the app, the warning will be replaced by the error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'edu.self.nyg.example.app.FooBar' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: foo,bar

For parameters names to be retained after compilation without the use of the debug flag, the `-parameters` flag must be used. This will allow Spring's [StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer.html) to replace `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer` and correctly find the proper beans for the foo and bar parameters of `someBean()`.

The use of `-parameters` seems to be recommended, but to get rid of the warning one can also do the following if needed:

```
@Bean
public SomeBean someBean(
        @Qualifier("foo") FooBar foo,
        @Qualifier("bar") FooBar bar) {
    return new SomeBean(foo, bar);
}
```

Note that it's ok to have both debug and parameters flags set to true, Spring will use `StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer` and won't emit a warning.

Comment: This is a much more complete answer! TBH, I just applied what the Spring framework told me in the logs without understanding what was going on. I was not even fully satisfied with my own answer, and that's the reason why I didn't accepted it. I will accept yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

As [pointed by @m-deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74600681/warning-printed-after-migrating-to-spring-boot-3-0-spring-integration-6-0#comment131681568_74600681) in the question’s comments, the problem is not related to Spring Boot or Spring Integration, but to Spring Framework itself. I needed to add the `-parameters` option to `javac`.

If you are using Maven, adding the following in the `pom.xml` should solve the problem:

```xml
<project>
  
  <!-- … -->

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.11.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <parameters>true</parameters>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <!-- … -->

</project>
```

Comment: setup for intellij: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217830/how-to-use-parameters-javac-option-in-intellij

Comment: If I use `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, not `maven-compiler-plugin` , How to config?

Comment: @RaphaëlColantonio You’re already using `maven-compiler-plugin` when the `compile` phase is invoked. This snippet tells Maven to use the `-parameters` flag when it compiles your sources.

Comment: You can even replace `<compilerArgs><arg>-parameters</arg></compilerArgs>` by `<parameters>true</parameters>`. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#parameters

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this is seen as a bug and will be fixed in Spring Framework 6.0.3.

> It looks like the core bean factory is unnecessarily retrieving constructor parameter names during the constructor autowiring algorithm, despite no constructor argument names having been specified. That's a bug we're going to fix in 6.0.3. [...] The warnings should disappear when running that same code on 6.0.3 then.

See
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29612#issuecomment-1333705627

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat irrelevant to Spring Integration, neither Spring Boot. The change has happened in Spring Framework by itself: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29563.

Yes, Spring Integration uses that `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer` in the `MessagePublishingInterceptor` for `@Publisher` to have method arguments as an `PublisherMetadataSource.ARGUMENT_MAP_VARIABLE_NAME` variable in a SpEL `EvaluationContext`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-publishing.html#message-publishing.

Another one is a `@MessagingGateway` where we try to resolve header names from `@Header` method params if you don't provide a `name` attribute for that annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#mapping-method-arguments

Similar logic is present in the `MessagingMethodInvokerHelper` to resolve header names for POJO service methods: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations

So, we need more info from your Spring Integration configuration to determine the place where you possible just would need to add a `name` attribute to the `@Header` annotation on your method param.

I also see that this one `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer` was deprecated in `6.0.1`. Please, raise a GH issue against Spring Integration, so we will fix it in favor of the mentioned `StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer`.

Comment: Whoops. Seems we crossposted. Do you mean adding the `-parameters` to `javac` is hiding a problem? Not adding a `name` attribute to the `@Header` may expose my application to future issues?

Comment: Not sure why issues. The point is that without `name` you have to compile your project with that `-parameters`: it cannot be without both. Although since it doesn't fail for you, probably your warning is not related to Spring Integration. Nevertheless it is better to fix Spring Integration anyway. So, open a GH issue to follow up. You may scan your code for `@Header` or so, but now I doubt you have the problem there...

Comment: Fixed with this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3956