# Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse

I am using Spring Boot 3.0.0, Eclipse IDE 2022-12, Java language level/JDK 19.

File `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring_jwt</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-security-jwt</name>
    <description>spring_jwt</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jasper report start. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-metadata</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-chart-themes</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-annotation-processors</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-castor</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberation-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-chart-customizers</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-custom-visualization</artifactId>
            <version>6.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jasper report end. -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--            <optional>true</optional>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>9.1.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-report</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-web</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-base</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-viewer</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-samples</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-webviewer</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-lib</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>stimulsoft-reports-webdesigner</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.stimulsoft</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>reports</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2022.3.3</version>-->
<!--            <type>pom</type>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>9.1.3</version>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>xpand</id>
            <name>xpand</name>
            <url>https://maven.xpand-it.com/artifactory/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven_central</id>
            <name>maven_central</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I have many controllers like these: File `UnitController.java`

```java
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.BLModel.Unit;
import com.example.BLModel.UnitId;
import com.example.service.UnitService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/unit")
public class UnitController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UnitController.class);

    @Autowired
    UnitService unitService;

    /**
     * Get all units belong to a tenant_id .<br/>
     * GET http://localhost:80/unit/1/all .
     *
     * @param tenant_id
     * @return
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/{tenant_id}/all")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Unit>> getAllUnits(@PathVariable("tenant_id") Short tenant_id) {
        LOGGER.info("Call method getAllUnits() .");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(unitService.getAll(tenant_id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * Get a unit by its composite primary key.<br/>
     * GET http://localhost:80/unit/1/42 .
     *
     * @param tenant_id
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/{tenant_id}/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Unit> viewDetailUnit(@PathVariable("tenant_id") Short tenant_id,
                                               @PathVariable("id") Short id) {
        LOGGER.info("Call method viewDetailUnit() .");
        UnitId unitId = new UnitId();
        unitId.setId(id);
        unitId.setTenantId(tenant_id);
        Optional<Unit> unitOptional = unitService.getById(unitId);
        Unit result = null;
        if (unitOptional.isPresent()) {
            result = unitOptional.get();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * Add a new unit.<br/>
     * POST http://localhost:80/unit
     *
     * @param input
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Unit> addUnit(@RequestBody Unit input) {
        LOGGER.info("Call method addUnit() .");
        Unit unit = new Unit();
        unit.setUnitName(input.getUnitName());
        unit.setDescription(input.getDescription());
        unit.setActiveStatus(input.getActiveStatus());
        Unit unitResult = unitService.add(unit);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(unitResult, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * Edit a unit.<br/>
     * PATCH http://localhost:80/unit/1/42 .
     *
     * @param tenant_id
     * @param id
     * @param input
     * @return
     */
    @PatchMapping(value = "/{tenant_id}/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Unit> editUnit(@PathVariable("tenant_id") Short tenant_id,
                                         @PathVariable("id") Short id,
                                         @RequestBody Unit input) {
        LOGGER.info("Call method editUnit() .");
        UnitId unitId = new UnitId();
        unitId.setTenantId(tenant_id);
        unitId.setId(id);
        Unit unit = (unitService.getById(unitId)).get();
        unit.setActiveStatus(input.getActiveStatus());
        unit.setDescription(input.getDescription());
        unit.setUnitName(input.getUnitName());
        Unit unitResult = unitService.add(unit);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(unitResult, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * Delete a specific unit.<br/>
     * DELETE http://localhost:80/unit/1/42 .
     *
     * @param tenant_id
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{tenant_id}/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteUnit(@PathVariable("tenant_id") Short tenant_id,
                                             @PathVariable("id") Short id) {
        UnitId unitId = new UnitId();
        unitId.setId(id);
        unitId.setTenantId(tenant_id);
        unitService.delete(unitId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

File `TimesheetSignController.java`

```java
package com.example.controller;

import com.example.BLModel.TimesheetSign;
import com.example.BLModel.TimesheetSignId;
import com.example.service.TimesheetSignService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/timesheet_sign")
public class TimesheetSignController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimesheetSignController.class);

    @Autowired
    TimesheetSignService timesheetSignService;

    /**
     * Get all time_sheet_sign by its tenant_id .<br/>
     * GET http://localhost:80/time_sheet_sign/1/all .
     *
     * @param tenant_id
     * @return
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/{tenant_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<TimesheetSign>> getAllAccounts(@PathVariable("tenant_id") Short tenant_id) {
        LOGGER.info("Call method getAllAccounts() .");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(timesheetSignService.getAll(tenant_id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * Get a specific time_sheet_sign item by its composite primary key.
     * GET http://localhost:80/1/42
     *
     * @param tenant_id
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "/{tenant_id}/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<TimesheetSign> viewDetailAccount(@PathVariable("tenant_id") Short tenant_id,
                                                           @PathVariable("id") Short id) {
        LOGGER.info("Call method viewDetailAccount() .");
        TimesheetSignId timesheetSignId = new TimesheetSignId();
        timesheetSignId.setId(id);
        timesheetSignId.setTenantId(tenant_id);
        Optional<TimesheetSign> timesheetSignOptional = timesheetSignService.getById(timesheetSignId);
        TimesheetSign timesheetSignResult = null;
        if (timesheetSignOptional.isPresent()) {
            timesheetSignResult = timesheetSignOptional.get();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(timesheetSignResult, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new time_sheet_sign .<br/>
     * POST http://localhost:80/time_sheet_sign
     *
     * @param input
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<TimesheetSign> addAccount(@RequestBody TimesheetSign input) {
        LOGGER.info("Call method addAccount() .");
        TimesheetSign timesheetSign = new TimesheetSign();
        timesheetSign.setTimesheetSignCode(input.getTimesheetSignCode());
        timesheetSign.setActiveStatus(input.getActiveStatus());
        timesheetSign.setIsDefault(input.getIsDefault());
        timesheetSign.setIsSystem(input.getIsSystem());
        timesheetSign.setIsHalfDay(input.getIsHalfDay());
        TimesheetSign timesheetSignResult = timesheetSignService.add(timesheetSign);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(timesheetSignResult, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * Edit time_sheet_sign by its composite primary key.
     * PATCH http://localhost:80/time_sheet_sign/1/42 .
     *
     * @param tenant_id
     * @param id
     * @param input
     * @return
     */
    @PatchMapping(value = "/{tenant_id}/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<TimesheetSign> editAccount(@PathVariable("tenant_id") Short tenant_id,
                                                     @PathVariable("id") Short id,
                                                     @RequestBody TimesheetSign input) {
        LOGGER.info("Call method editAccount() .");
        TimesheetSignId timesheetSignId = new TimesheetSignId();
        timesheetSignId.setTenantId(tenant_id);
        timesheetSignId.setId(id);
        TimesheetSign timesheetSign = (timesheetSignService.getById(timesheetSignId)).get();
        timesheetSign.setTimesheetSignName(input.getTimesheetSignName());
        timesheetSign.setIsHalfDay(input.getIsHalfDay());
        timesheetSign.setIsSystem(input.getIsSystem());
        timesheetSign.setTimesheetSignCode(input.getTimesheetSignCode());
        timesheetSign.setSalaryRate(input.getSalaryRate());
        TimesheetSign timesheetSignResult = timesheetSignService.add(timesheetSign);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(timesheetSignResult, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /**
     * Delete time_sheet_sign by its composite primary key.
     * DELETE http://localhost:80/time_sheet_sign/1/42 .
     *
     * @param tenant_id
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{tenant_id}/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> deleteAccount(@PathVariable("tenant_id") Short tenant_id,
                                                @PathVariable("id") Short id) {
        TimesheetSignId timesheetSignId = new TimesheetSignId();
        timesheetSignId.setId(id);
        timesheetSignId.setTenantId(tenant_id);
        timesheetSignService.delete(timesheetSignId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

```java
[2m2022-12-19T08:18:19.517+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m7048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8082-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
[2m2022-12-19T08:18:19.520+07:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m7048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8082-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 3 ms
[2m2022-12-19T08:18:21.177+07:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m7048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8082-exec-8][0;39m [36mocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.example.controller.UnitController
[2m2022-12-19T08:18:21.313+07:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m7048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8082-exec-8][0;39m [36mocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.example.controller.TimesheetSignController
[2m2022-12-19T08:18:21.331+07:00[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m7048[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8082-exec-8][0;39m [36mocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.example.controller.TaxAgentInfoController
```

[image]

Full log https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/45b15558e76164e83bdbc0117c9cf64f

How to avoid/resolve this warning?
P/S: Comment about not dupplicated question. In this question and solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/74601911/3728901 , use `maven-compiler-plugin` , not `spring-boot-maven-plugin` .

Comment: Raphael, is your question answered?

Answer (score 12):

This is a known bug and [there is a Spring Issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29612) for it. But it is not harmful and you do not need to take any action unless you just don't want warnings in your logs.

From the issue:

"It looks like the core bean factory is unnecessarily retrieving constructor parameter names during the constructor autowiring algorithm, despite no constructor argument names having been specified. That's a bug we're going to fix in [Spring Framework] 6.0.3."

and

"For the time being, you may simply disable the warn log category for org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer. There is unnecessary reading of class files in the meantime but otherwise no harm for your application."

Comment: I'm on Spring framework 6.0.8 and still see this warning message.

Comment: @ArunGowda If the warning concerns your own classes then it's not a Spring bug but an issue with how your code is compiled. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74601911 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/75629035.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using **spring-context** version **6.0.11** and the problem still exists.

### SHORT ANSWER:

Add this build plugin to the *pom.xml* file of your project:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>-parameters</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If you already have this plugin in your *pom.xml* file then just add configuration part to the existing Maven compiler plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <compilerArgs>
        <arg>-parameters</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
</configuration>
```

---

### MORE DETAILED ANSWER:

[Apache Maven Compiler Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin) is used to compile the sources of your Maven project.

When you specify this plugin in your project you can add configuration to it:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

For example, if you want to use the Java 8 language features (`-source 1.8`) and also want the compiled classes to be compatible with JVM 1.8 (`-target 1.8`), you can either add the two following configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
```

Another configuration we can specify is passing arguments to the Java compiler (**javac**):

```
<configuration>
    <compilerArgs>
        <arg>-parameters</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
</configuration>
```

We passed `-parameters` as an additional argument to the compiler.
And of course both preceding configurations can be used together.

Answer (score 4):

In my particular case, I am using Springboot 3.0.12 and was getting this warning from a controller class, where we have an endpoint that looks like below.

```
  @GetMapping("employees/{id}")
    public Employee getEmployeeById(@PathVariable String id) {
        //... some logic
    }
```

After reading the warning log a few times, I understood that spring is trying to resolve the parameter name mapping and, in that process, it is using a deprecated "-debug" flag which is being logged as a warning.

So, I had changed the method signature i.e. I myself explicitly provided the mapping like below which fixed the issue in my case:

```
  @GetMapping("employees/{id}")
        public Employee getEmployeeById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
            //... some logic
        }
```

I thought this might help someone who has a similar problem so posted it.

Thanks.

Comment: That is exactly the problem I had. I had a lot of cases where I was just letting the default @PathVariable be the one in the url, but changing it to the explicit name quieted these warnings. Cheers!